# Facebook feed image size

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a message on my wall via facebook graph api. I set a picture parameter (an external url) and a message parameter. The message itself contains a link. When the item gets posted to the feed, however, an image is shown as a very small thumbnail and there's a link to my website next to it (on the right). What i want to do instead is to make the thumbnail appear full width on the post (like when you post via facebook itself). I don't set the link to my website anywhere, only picture url and message parameters are set - so where is it comming from and is there a way to remove it and make the picture appear right below the message, taking full width of the post?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

To display a picture with full width, your picture size must be in `1200x630` for best display on high resolution device.

[Facebook sharing best practice](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices)